# Gradle Plugin resolve artifact

Tags: plugins, gradle, dependency-management

Is it possible for a Gradle plugin to resolve an artifact on its own? I know that in Maven, plugins can inject the Aether [RepositorySystem](http://sonatype.github.io/sonatype-aether/apidocs/org/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem.html) and use that to download artifacts (That's how the [Appengine Maven Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/) downloads the Appengine SDK). Is there similar functionality in Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve but there are two things you could do when it comes to adding artifacts to a project with a plugin:

- simply add the dependency you wish to be resolved to one of project's configurations using the plugin and let Gradle resolve it for you
- add a custom configuration and do whatever you need to do with the resolved artifact, just like gradle gae plugin does for downloading gae sdk [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/gae/GaePlugin.groovy#L86) and [here](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/gae/GaePlugin.groovy#L161)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize plugins could configure dependencies like that.